# Менять изображение кнопки по нажатию UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Написал вот такой код, получается при нажатии на button если его изображение равно star_inactive, то ставить изображение star_active и наоборот

```
 @IBAction func star_click(sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImage(named:"star_active") != nil {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"star_inactive.png"), forControlState: [])
        }
        if UIImage(named:"star_inactive") != nil {
            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"star_active.png"), forControlState: [])
        }
    }
```

Но только когда я нажимаю на кнопку она меняется один раз, обратно при повторном нажатии она не меняется.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по логике вашего кода вы делаете проверку на существование изображения.

Попробуйте так:

```
@IBAction func star_click(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "star_active") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"star_inactive.png"), forControlState: .normal)
    }
    else {
        sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"star_active.png"), forControlState: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло